# Python - append value from dataframe to corresponding tuple element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

Suppose i have a dataframe like:

```
Name | Level
Jack    1
John    2
Mike    1
Mark    2
```

and after some processing, I end up with a randomized list of tuples with `Names` pairs:

`[('Jack','Mark'),('Jack','John'),('Mark','Mike')]`

Is it possible to return the `Level` of each element in the tuple.. like:

`[('Jack','Mark',1,2),('Jack','John',1,2),('Mark','Mike',2,1)]`

OR take the difference between elements inside the tuple?:

`[('Jack','Mark',-1),('Jack','John',-1),('Mark','Mike',1)]`

I may have dug myself into a hole, and I'm looking to dig up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `pd.Series.get`

```
d = df.set_index('Name').Level
```

`dict.get` would've worked as well: `d = dict(zip(df.Name, df.Level)`

```
a = [('Jack','Mark'),('Jack','John'),('Mark','Mike')]

[t + tuple(map(d.get, t)) for t in a]

[('Jack', 'Mark', 1, 2), ('Jack', 'John', 1, 2), ('Mark', 'Mike', 2, 1)]
```

And

```
[t + (d[t[0]] - d[t[1]],) for t in a]

[('Jack', 'Mark', -1), ('Jack', 'John', -1), ('Mark', 'Mike', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'Name': ['Jack', 'John', 'Mike', 'Mark'],
        'Level': [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
)

pairs = [('Jack','Mark'),('Jack','John'),('Mark','Mike')]

def get_level(df, name):
    return df[df['Name'] == name]['Level'].values[0]
```

```
new_pairs = []

for pair in pairs:
    new_pairs.append(
        (
            pair[0], pair[1], get_level(df, pair[0]), get_level(df, pair[1])
        )
    )
```